# Unity mathematical Rule to deduce the value from given maximum value in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, math, windows-phone-8.1, symbolic-math

I know its a very silly question I am sorry for that but I wanted to know how to apply Unity Rule(Maths) in C#. I have a TotalScore variable(T) that ranges from 0-18, and I have a ring progress bar of which the values ranges from 0-360. How can I carry the following function out in C#...

> if 18 = 360 degree,
>   then 1 = 360/18 degree
>   thus T = ? degree      //where T is the TotalScore.

Comment: You want the same ratio to 360 as you have to 18: `(totalScore / 18) * 360`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

18T = 360 degree progress

1T = 360/18 = 20 degree progress.

So the following one line will do..

Progress bar = T * 20